# Call to a member function find() on a non-object SimpleHtmlDom

Tags: php, mysqli, simple-html-dom

При парсинге цен магазина *DNS* столкнулся с этой проблемой и никак не могу решить её ... Посоветуйте пожалуйста что нужно изменить в коде чтобы он наконец заработал ???

Вот собственно код :

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen','1');
defined('PHPFOX') or exit('NO DICE!');
require(PHPFOX_DIR_LIB . 'simplehtmldom' . PHPFOX_DS . 'simple_html_dom.php');
class Parser_Component_Controller_Updateshop extends Phpfox_Component
{
    public function process()
    {
        $aRows = Phpfox::getLib('database')
            ->select('id, linkdns')             
            ->from(Phpfox::getT('parser'))
            ->execute('getRows');
        foreach ($aRows as $iKey => $aRow)
        {
            $iId = $aRows[$iKey]['id'];         
            $sLink = $aRows[$iKey]['linkdns'];
            $curl = curl_init(); 
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $sLink);  
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);  
            $str = curl_exec($curl);  
            curl_close($curl);  

            $Html= str_get_html($str);
            $Item = $Html->find('a[class=ec-price-item-link]', 0);
            if (is_object($Item))
                {
                    $ItemLink = $Item->href;
                }else {
                    $SubItemLink = $Html->find('meta[itemprop=price]', 0);
                    if(is_object($SubItemLink)){
                        $ItemLink = $SubItemLink->content;
                    }else{
                        $ItemLink = 'not_found';
                    }
                }
            $Html->clear(); // подчищаем за собой
            unset($Html);
            $sql="UPDATE phpfox_parser_dns SET itemdns='$ItemLink' id='$iId' ";
            Phpfox::getLib('database')->query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Изменил код на вот это но проблема не изменилась. Может, я не в ту сторону рою ?

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen','1');
defined('PHPFOX') or exit('NO DICE!');
require(PHPFOX_DIR_LIB . 'simplehtmldom' . PHPFOX_DS . 'simple_html_dom.php');
class Parser_Component_Controller_Updateshop extends Phpfox_Component
{
    public function process()
    {
        $aRows = Phpfox::getLib('database')
            ->select('id, linkdns')

            ->from(Phpfox::getT('parser'))
            ->execute('getRows');
        foreach ($aRows as $iKey => $aRow)
        {
            $iId = $aRows[$iKey]['id'];

            $sLink = $aRows[$iKey]['linkdns'];
            $curl = curl_init(); 
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $sLink);

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);

            $str = curl_exec($curl);

            curl_close($curl);

            $Html= str_get_html($str);//получаем страницу
            //$Item = $Html->find('a[class=ec-price-item-link]', 0);//ищем нужный тэг
            if (is_object($Item = $Html->find('a[class=ec-price-item-link]', 0)))//вот тут код матерится Call to a member function find() on a non-object
                {
                    $ItemLink = $Item->href;//получаем ссылку кнопки
                    $SSItemLink = 'http://www.dns-shop.ru' . $ItemLink;
                    $SubItemLink = $Html->find('meta[itemprop=price]', 0);
                    $ItemLink = $SubItemLink->content;
                }else {
                    //$SubItemLink = $Html->find('meta[itemprop=price]', 0);
                    if(is_object($SubItemLink = $Html->find('meta[itemprop=price]', 0))){
                        $ItemLink = $SubItemLink->content;
                    }else{
                        $ItemLink = 'not_found';
                    }
                }
            $Html->clear(); // подчищаем за собой
            unset($Html);
            $sql="UPDATE phpfox_parser_dns SET itemdns='$ItemLink' id='$iId' ";
            Phpfox::getLib('database')->query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: сделайте дамп str и Html, по всей видимости, у вас что-то не так загрузилось. и имя поиска в find, наверное, надо взять в кавычки

Comment: Простите а оно разве не в кавычках ???

Comment: `class="ec-price-item-link"`

Comment: нет изменений от кавычек

Comment: После `$Html= str_get_html($str);` попробуйте `var_dump(error_get_last());` добавить и добавте результат к вопросу.

Comment: var_dump(error_get_last()); вывел NULL 326 раз

Comment: CURL что ли неправильно работает ??? Сссыль для парсинга далеко не нуль ...

Comment: `var_dump($Html,$str); die; ` после `str_get_html($str);` покажите что вывело.

Comment: NULL выдает и там и там